# Правильное написание слова Смарт супервайзер

Tags: слитно-дефис

Всем здравствуйте! Есть ли у кого-нибудь достоверная информация из компетентных источников о том, каково верное написание слова *смарт супервайзер*? Есть варианты: *смарт супервайзер*; *смарт-супервайзер*; ну и наконец, *смартсупервайзер*...  Сама я склоняюсь к написанию через дефис... Но может ли кто-нибудь поделиться своими соображениями?..

Answer (score 2):

"Верное написание" в русском языке - это соответствующее словарным нормам. Этот термин пока не вошел в словари русского языка, поэтому нормы написания не существует.

Но аналогичные термины с приставкой "смарт" рекомендуют писать через дефис: "смарт-часы", "смарт-телевизор". См. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82-

Comment: Ну, спасибо. Про Грамоту и дефис я и сама знала... Но надеялась, что, быть может, кто-то по работе сталкивался с этим новым модным словом...